# datetime compare with stored datetime in TABLE in ORACLE SQL Query

Tags: oracle

I've one table in that date is stored as '**23/06/2018 10:51:49**' and so on for each transaction. I want to fetch data between two dates like '**22-jun-2018 23:00:01**' and '**23-jun-2018 23:00:00**'.

Comment: Just to clarify - is it stored in the table in a `varchar` column with that format?

Comment: It is stored as date

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `to_date` function to convert those literals to `date`s, and then use the regular `between` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  mydate BETWEEN TO_DATE('22-jun-2018 23:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND
                      TO_DATE('23-jun-2018 23:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Thank you very much SIR.